# Как использовать (геометрический) Vector в с#

Tags: c#, winforms

В документации Майкрософт есть структура двумерного вектора `Vector` https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.vector?view=net-5.0, однако я не могу его найти в своём проекте на винформс. как его можно подключить?

Comment: Вам же даны примеры в документации.

Comment: @aepot Я имею в виду что я даже не могу объявить вектор, его просто нет в пространстве имён, в документации указано `System.Windows`, но там ничего нет.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась следующим образом: нужно в ссылках в обозревателе решений добавить ссылку на `WindowsBase` и тогда вектора появятся.